# Information System with user-generated Apps

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, sandbox

I'm developing a web platform with some basic functionality, an API and an integrated Apps concept (similar to the concept of, e.g., Facebook Apps). This I know how to do, but the challenge is that I want to host the Apps for the users, and I want to distribute computation power and bandwidth to the Apps according to their usage (which is a dynamic behavior).

I don't want to get locked into a specific software development framework in terms of the Apps, and therefor the only solution I see is sand-boxing Apache instances for each App in some way, and dynamically modifying the limitations of such sandboxes.

How would you approach this? Do you know about resources I could read into about things like that?

Thanks a lot for your input,
HGN.

Answer (score 0):

Why make apache mandatory?

Why not just host a virtual machine, there are loads of managment facilities for doing that and prior art.

Comment: With a lot of integrated Apps (we are talking about, say, ~400), wouldn't the overload of the virtual machines be quite intense?

Comment: Probably, 400 apache instances isn't going to be light weight though. The difference to me would be tooling, I don't know anyone who gives out apache sandboxed, where as there are lots of vitual machine hosts. Not convinced it would be worth spending all the money to tool up for the apache concept, vs just using off the shelf  virtual machine managment.